# Javascript: accessing a given index in an array that is an object property

Tags: javascript, arrays, extendscript

Say I have the following object:

```
var obj = {
   "a": Array(),
   "b": Array()
}
```

And I want to add values to those two arrays. Can I use the following notation?

```
for (i=0; i < 100; i++) {
   obj["a"][i] = (whatever);
   obj["b"][i] = (whatever);
   }
```

The docs I've read say that this kind of nested notation (`obj["a"][3]`) is for accessing nested objects, not necessarily arrays that are in an object. Is there any difference? If it's not possible, how should I do it?

(Actually, I'm writing for ExtendScript, but it's similar enough to Javascript that I thought that I would tag it about Javascript too).

Comment: Yep, this is legal syntax.

Comment: It's valid in javascript. Not sure about ExtendScript

Comment: The easiest way to find out is to try it, isn't it?

Comment: Does the code not work for you?  What is your actual question?

Comment: I was just asking whether it was the right syntax, since I couldn't find clear enough references in the docs. As it turns out, my code didn't work at first... so it was quite helpful to be reassured that the syntax was right when debugging.

Comment: you could also do obj["a"].push("whatever"); in the for loop as well I believe.

Answer (score 1):

About javascript: In js everything (including arrays) is an object. So, your code is valid. You can also use obj.a[i], but the way you used it is ok.

About ExtendScript: Did not managed (in my 2 min of searching) to find any clear documentation about this, but I've seen something similar so it MAY be ok <- some1 please correct me if I'm wrong. You could just assign it then print your object to be sure.